# How can I display a loading image, or a progress bar, for a new tab while waiting for the MVC call to return?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML button in the file generateReport.cshtml, that opens a new tab to display the report:

```
<div>
   <a id="btnPreviewPDF" class="btn" href="#" title="Preview Report" target="_blank">Preview</a>
</div>
```

This kicks off an MVC GET in reportController.cs that creates the model to be used by the html that renders the report:

```
[GET("PreviewPdf/{id:int}/{reportDate}")]
        public virtual ActionResult PreviewReport(int id, string reportDate)
        {            
            var helper = new ReportHelper(client);
            var model = helper.GenerateViewModelForPreviewReport(id, reportDate);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Then the above model is used in viewReport.cshtml as a model to display the data, for example:

```
@model Reports.ReportHelper

<div class="sub-header-text primary-orange text-bold">
   Summary: @Model.ReportDate.ToString("MMMM") @Model.ReportDate.ToString("yyyy")
</div>
```

Waiting for the PreviewReport to return in the GET of reportController.cs can take 30+ seconds to run so I would like to display a loading image/gif on the new tab that's created by clicking the 'Preview' button. Since this GET command is running before the HTML code in viewReport.cshtml I have not been able to figure out a way to do this. I would like to display a loading image on that new tab and prevent the browser from throwing a message thinking that the page is not responding. Can anyone help or link me to a some info? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty div with an id on the page. Before the ajax call, set the html

`$("#loadingDiv").html("Loading...");`

On success of your ajax call, remove the html from the div

`$("#loadingDiv").html("");`

This uses jQuery btw, but if you're not using that, I'm sure you can do it in plain old javascript too.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about state. When you first load the page everything is loading. So show the user by default that you are loading the page. Then after your loading has completed, select the `html` tag and add a class to it to indicate to your page that the loading is done. Set your styles according to the *loading* and *finished* states.

Example below:

```js
console.log('loading');

setTimeout(function() {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('finished');
  console.log('finished loading');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.loader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.loader::before,
.loader::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse 2s normal infinite;
}

.loader::after {
  animation-delay: 200ms
}

html.finished .loader {
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  75%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="loader">
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, none of the HTML is being loaded on the new tab until after the GET call has completed. So the div will not load until after the waiting

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to utilize unobtrusive AJAX. All you would need is to install Microsoft jQuery unobtrusive AJAX from your Nuget Package Manager.

Download a loading GIF.

Then, in your view, call the following:

```
@{using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", null, new AjaxOptions()
     {
          HttpMethod = "POST",
          LoadingElementId = "divName",
          // ...
     }
}))
{
     // Html code goes here
     <div id="divName" class="col-md-12 text-center align-self-center" style="display:none;">
         <img src="~/Images/LoadingCircle.gif" alt="Loading..." />
     </div>
}
```

This div will then only display when it is loading